# What is the bundle in the Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, bundle

I downloaded the Facebook SDK, and I find there has something like `FBConnect.bundle` it is very interesting, and I also find some code is using the bundle, like this:

```
[loginButton setImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/LoginWithFacebookNormal@2x.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So, I would like to know, what is the bundle? How can I know what inside the bundle? How can I create my own bundle? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bundles are more relevant on OS X than they are on iOS.  A bundle is simply a self contained executable file.  When you run it, it executes a main function that is defined inside, and uses only the resources that it contains.  However, iOS (as far as I know) doesn't (can't?) execute bundles aside from the main one, so they are just glorified folders.  You can view their contents by going to the in the finder, right clicking, and choosing *Show Package Contents*.

Comment: Bundles are not necessarily (and often aren't) executable.

Comment: @JoshHudnall From the Apple docs:  A **bundle** is a directory with a standardized hierarchical structure that holds executable code and the resources used by that code.  But actually, I use them sometimes when I just want to group some things together so I understand your point.

Comment: You're right. I was confusing packages with bundles. I forget that they're not synonymous.

Comment: so, bundle is some zipped directory - why doesn't apple simply use directories?

Comment: @Novellizator They are not zipped.  They are just shown a different way in the Finder.  If you navigate to them in Terminal you can enter them just like folders because that is what they are (Just like applications are folders too)